# How to fetch the value of the checkbox that is stored in name array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, ruby-on-rails, javascript-objects

[image]

As im dispalying the check boxes with buttons in UI for user to check the books that they currently using, as fivebooks array contains book name and the publication details of the book, as the user checked the allbooks[][] array will hold those checked book data

for example:
`allbooks[0][1,2]` it contains book 1 and 2 if the user of firstlibrary(0th index) clicked check boxes of 1, and 2

as i need to fetch the allbooks[][] array and view the values

so how to fetch the array and view the values of the array

in allbooks array first index will be the library index

it means there will be morethan one library and each library has five books

i need to fetch the array and view the books that are currently checked

fivebooks array

```
var fivebooks = {
   "how_it_flys":1, "players_in_ground":2, "lets_Start_gaming":3, "gaming_stars":4,
   "invisible_man":5
 }
```

Comment: Do not post images of code, as they can't be debugged. Intead post runnable code, as snippet. Ideally, you should create a *runnable* [mcve].

Comment: You'll need to (also) include an sample of `fivebooks` and `allbooks`.  Where would/do you "fetch" the array from?

Comment: Your example for `fivebooks` is not an array

Answer (score 0):

After generate your DOM you can for exemple

```
const checkboxs = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]');
for (var i = 0; i < checkboxs.length; i++) {
  console.log(checkboxs[i].checked);
}
```